# how to run app django channels with supervisor and gunicorn or daphne

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord, django-channels, daphne

I have a problem with my configuration from supervisor, my app is using django_channles well, when I run my app using of two codes below 
working well

```
(myenv)/colonybit/colonybitbasics/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

or

```
(myenv)/colonybit/colonybitbasics/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
```

and I have other app in vuejs, the code above is working, but when I try run my app with this code below like this

```
(myenv)/colonybit/ ./bin/start.sh
```

my file start.sh

```
NAME="colony_app"
DJANGODIR=/home/ubuntu/colonybit         # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/ubuntu/colonybit/run/gunicorn.sock  
USER=ubuntu                                         # the user to run as
GROUP=ubuntu                                        # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                       
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=colonybit.settings      
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=colonybit.asgi              # ASGI module name
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/ubuntu/colonybit/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec colonybit ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
     --name $NAME \
     --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
     --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
     --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 \
     --log-level=debug \
     --log-file=-
```

the server is running well, but my app in vuejs, show me an error 500,  can't cossuming my app in django_channels

please told me, how to config my file start.sh for working using ASGI

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your django app works with its development server, because this server handles both http and websocket requests for you. Now looks your problem is with production, and gunicorn couldn't handle both requests, so daphne comes to play.

A BF way to solve it is to start the daphne ASGI within another file, which contains- exec daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 $DJANGO_ASGI_MODULE:application (note the different port used here), other parts of the two files should be quite similar. Lately, you can refer to this for more sight, or see whether abandon unix sockets is necessary (it works for me): https://github.com/django/channels/issues/919#issuecomment-422346729

Once you've done this, integrate with supervisor to make your run simple and stable.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this:

> "integrate with supervisor to make your run simple and stable"


How would one go about doing that? Supervisor docs don't seem very helpful

Comment: Hi, the reason using Supervisor is to simplify the process of running your web service, as I think it does nothing but help you starting/managing several processes. In this case, you need to start the two app servers, and probably databases, like redis, to invoke the web service. With supervisor, you simply add these processes as programs to a Supervisor group, start the tool, and you're done with it. Otherwise, you have to run commands/a shell script with config for each process that needed.